No encryption on Samsung Xcover 7
On the Android smartphones I have used so far (e.g. devices from Sony, Motorola, Google or Nokia), there was always an option somewhere in the settings that allowed the smartphone to be encrypted. As far as I can remember, this option was always active by default and the file system was therefore encrypted. This observation is also supported by my research, according to which at least newer Android devices are generally delivered with encryption activated (e.g. here).
I have now received a new Samsung Xcover 7 and have unfortunately realised that it does not meet my requirements. For this reason, I would like to send it back to the dealer. Of course, all private data should be removed from the device beforehand. So far, I have always assumed that a factory reset would be sufficient to achieve this, as the actual data is encrypted. To make sure that the data is really encrypted, I checked the settings. However, I could not find the above-mentioned option there. I therefore asked Samsungs Support Chat whether the Xcover 7 is encrypted by default and was only told that this is not the case. My comment that I could not find an option to activate encryption in the settings was answered as follows: „I do understand your concern. However, we do not advise encrypting your device as it may affect your devices' software.“
Did the support employee (Samsung UK) simply have no idea or does his statement correspond to reality? I asked the same question again in the German Samsung support chat and got the answer that the device is not encrypted be default.

You already included the link to the correct question and in it's answer you find all the information you need. That you don't find an encryption option is because encryption is mandatory for all Google Android devices. Therefore it is no longer shown in any option because it is mandatory. And for the same reason the support doesn't know anything about this type of encryption because users don't recognize that there is encryption active. That is my guess.

Samsung has an official documentation about encryption. Additional methods to check: Is there a way for a user to tell if their Android device is encrypted or not?
